# meaning of: Did you question all the answers

Tags: phrase-meaning

I don't speak English, I learnt it at school and I like to read some English books, and the lyrics of songs. So forgive my bad English.

Reading the lyrics of the song of [Crosby, Stills & Nash - Wasted On The way](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/crosbystillsnash/wastedontheway.html), there are some phrases I don't understand, in particular the following:

> Did you question all the answers

It is an interrogative. I think it is an unusual form because someone can:

- answer a question;
- or ask a question.

My interpretation of the phrase is:
"Considering all the answers you have received to all the questions you asked till now, did you ever ask yourself why you had received those particular answers?"

Please, can you tell me what would be the correct interpretation? And does there exist an alternative phrase to express it? Many thanks! (:

Comment: We assume answers/conclusions on some topic given to us are correct and to our benefit, but that is often not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpreting song lyrics is often difficult because the context is sparse and rhythm and musicality are more important to the songwriter than correct grammar.

I agree with your interpretation. Note that the question refers to a past time (`when you were young'), not up till the present time. To me, such a sentence most likely means:
`Were you critical about all the answers that you got (when you were young)? I hope you didn't take everything at face value.'